# Remove Wordpress Theme Widget Support

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating a theme for a customer using the latest version of Wordpress. The theme/design for their website doesn't not display widgets or a sidebar. How can I remove the "Widgets" link from the sidebar in the admin panel? Also, under the "Manage Themes" page The options for my theme say "Widgets | Menus". I would also like to remove the "Widgets" link if possible.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [skitch.com](https://img.skitch.com/20110501-7nppbyfsn6rb5j37itxdnrqgy.png))</sub>

Comment: if you dont register the sidebar , the widgets will not appear

Answer (score -1):

This can be done by altering the global $menu array described in this article.

http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-remove-menus-in-wordpress-dashboard

Unregister the theme options shuld be possible by overridable in the childthemes functions.php file.